# Difference between flex: 0 0 33% and flex 0 1 33%

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

What's the difference between those to flex-items properties and which one I should use in order to build a grid system ?
For example bootstrap system and ant-design uses flex: 0 0 33 and max-width: 33% (as an example). Why the dont use flex: 0 1 33 for example.

Comment: *Why they dont use flex: 0 1 33 for example.* --> only them can answer

Answer (score 0):

`/* Three values: flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis */`

`flex: 0 0 33%;`

The flex-grow CSS property sets the flex grow factor of a flex item's main size.

The flex-shrink CSS property sets the flex shrink factor of a flex item. If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container, items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink.

The flex-basis CSS property sets the initial main size of a flex item. It sets the size of the content box unless otherwise set with box-sizing.

To answer you question, the reason they use that property is to maintain consistence of rows and columns, it means they will have a max with of 33% and will neither shrink nor grow as opposed to yours where you have a flex-shrink of 1.
This will cause the item to collapse incase the contents are bigger than the parent element.